# How to share a cash prize among multiple entries in position A, B and C

Tags: algorithms, fair-division

How to share a cash prize among entries in position *A*, *B* and *C*. Each position can have multiple entries. Each entry in position *A* should have *50%* more of the cash prize than each entry in position *B*. Each entry in position *B* should have *10%* more than each entry in position *C*.

How can we calculate the prize share for an entry in position *A*, position *B* and position *C* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ be the number of entries in A,B,C respectively. Then we know $ax_a + bx_b + cx_c = 1$ where $x_i$ is the prize share for an entry in position $i$. Given the other two constraints, $x_a = 1.5 x_b$ and $x_b = 1.1x_c$, we get $$cx_c + 1.1bx_c + 1.65ax_c =1,$$
$$x_c = \frac{1}{c+1.1b+1.65a}.$$
From there, clearly 
$$x_b = \frac{1.1}{c+1.1b+1.65a}$$
$$x_a = \frac{1.65}{c+1.1b+1.65a}.$$

Comment: Let's test this equation with _a_ = 10, _b_ = 5 and _c_ = 2. Cash Prize = 10 000. Let's calculate the prize share for an entry in position A, B and C.

Comment: Just plug in a,b,c into the given formulas, and multiply the numbers $x_a, x_b, x_c$ by 10,000.

Comment: Rounded off answers are Xc=425.53,  Xb=458.33, Xa=687.50. But here seems to be the issue: Xa has to be 50% more than Xb. And Xb has to be 10% more than Xc.

Comment: 687.5 is indeed 50% more than 458.33, and somehow you managed to even calculate $X_c$ wrong since that one is 416.67...

Comment: It's working. Please let me know how you found the constants 1, 1.1 and 1.65

Comment: b is 10% more than c, so b = 1.1c. Adding 10% means multiplying by 1.1...Afterwards a is 50% more than b, so a = 1.5b = 1.5*1.1c = 1.65c